# Testing the Controller with RSpec, Devise, Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller, factory-bot

I have models: Post and User(Devise). I am testing controller Post.

```
describe "If user sign_in" do

   before(:all){ 
     @user = Factory(:user)
   }

   it "should get new" do
     sign_in @user  
     get 'new'
     response.should be_success
     response.should render_template('posts/new')
   end

   it "should create post" do
     sign_in @user
     post 'create', :post => Factory(:post)
     response.should redirect_to(post_path(:post))
   end
 end
```

But the second test fails:

> Failure/Error: post 'create', :post => Factory(:post)
>        ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
>          Validation failed: Email has already been taken, Email has already been taken, Username has already been taken

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a tool to clean your database between tests. Because you should be able to run each test with a clean database. I'm using [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner), it's quite a famous gem and it works really well. It's easy to setup too. An example from the README ( RSpec related):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Comment: When i include your code in spec_helper. I got an error Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       SQLite3::SQLException: cannot start a transaction within a transaction: begin transaction

Comment: you don't need another gem for this.

Comment: I found the SQLite exception solution was to remove the `clean_with(:truncation)` and change the strategy entirely to `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation`

Answer (score 9):

You don't need another gem for this. FactoryGirl has built in dynamic helpers for this. I suggest watching the short [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures-revised) about this. Here is a snippet of how it works:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:username) { |n| "foo#{n}" }
    password "foobar"
    email { "#{username}@example.com" }
```

Comment: If you are a rails developer and not using Railcasts, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: but if you are a TRUE Rails developer, then you should link to free content first and then suggest the paid one